# Sybase SQL anywhere 11 Grant/Revoke on column views

Tags: sql, view, sybase, sql-grant, sqlanywhere

My objective is to hide some column values to specific user or group on my views.
I managed to give access to views, tables or table column with

`GRANT SELECT [(MY COLUMN)] ON TABLE/VIEW TO MY_USER`

for this query I have this error :

> GRANT of column permission on view not allowed

But how can I block access to column in view ? (if I can't GRANT, it's also impossible with REVOKE I guess)

a simple example :

```
 CREATE VIEW AIRLINE_LIST 
        (ICAO_CODE,AIRLINE_NAME)
    AS SELECT 
        ARL_CODE,ARL_NAME
    FROM AIRLINE
```

so here I want that user TEST can see the AIRLINE_NAME data's but not the AIRLINE_CODE data's

Comment: Why don't you create another view, lacking unwanted/restricted columns, specifically for targeted users group?

Comment: The problem is that I have 16 users group and more than 30 views and
each user group will have different restriction for each view

Comment: You can grant/revoke access to a column on any TABLE but, as far as I know, you can not do that for views. I understand your pain but sometimes we need to bite the bullet and do the hard work (I assume you don't want to "pollute" table space with all these nooks and crannies of different users groups and their restrictions and it is a sensible thing to avoid it imho too ) =] Good luck.

Comment: Thx for your reply :)
I'll wait to see if anyone has another solution and keep searching better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. From the [SQL Anywhere 11 docs](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#1101/en/dbreference_en11/grant-statement.html*d5e40359): "*SELECT permissions on columns cannot be granted for views, only for tables*".

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Are there any other solution for my issue ?
Or maybe should I create views for each user as Alp said

Comment: If you want to block access to certain columns, couldn't you just give them access to only those columns in the original table? If the view is more complicated than that (i.e. has a where clause, or is a join or something), then yes, you'll have to create different views for each user.